# Prevent installation of Viber in Domain Computer

Tags: installation, group-policy, viber

We have standard domain where running executables require administrative privileges but when I get Viber and run it installs without prompting admin password, I do not know what type of installation is that, I want to prevent it by Group Policy. Need Help how to do that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Group Policy to use is
*Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Don’t run specified Windows applications*.

Set the policy to Enabled, select "Show..." and add the executable name (`??.exe`).

Press OK twice to terminate.

You may also do so in the registry at
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\DisallowRun`, using values created as "DWORD (32-bit)" and named `1`, `2` etc
whose values are the executables to block (`??.exe`).

For more details see
[Prevent Users From Running Certain Programs](https://www.technipages.com/prevent-users-from-running-certain-programs).