# How can I block the installation of a program in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, installation, setup

I have a problem with a PC game, to which I've become quite addicted. It has slowly become a problem that affects my day-to-day life, and I want to stop it. I've uninstalled the game countless times, but my will power is weak, and, sooner or later, I always end up reinstalling it.

This may sound like a joke, but to me it's a serious problem, so I would like to know if there is any way to configure my Windows 10 laptop so that it is not possible to install this specific game.

I know that the permission to install programs can be restricted to the administrator, but I am interested in forbidding specifically the installation of the game, and not the installation of other software.

Could someone please help me with this task?

Comment: Get Autoruns 64 from Microsoft SysInternals.  Run it and see if you can find the startup settings for the program and remove the items so it will not start again.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1518636/prevent-installation-of-viber-in-domain-computer/1518659#1518659 . But how are you going to prevent yourself from undoing any changes?

Comment: Any steps you can take yourself to prevent installation can also be undone by yourself to allow installation again.

Answer (score 3):

Any measure you install you can also quickly undo. You need to enlist the help of a friend
that has a good knowledge of Windows and is willing to help you.

I suggest creating a new Windows account for your friend with administrator
permission. He will use his account to create procedures that will make it
impossible to play the game.

Some ideas for your friend:

- Change his login password and keep it a secret
- Encrypt the game folder so it is only usable by himself, perhaps using the
  [Encrypting File System (EFS)](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/encrypting-file-system-efs-windows-10)
- Write a script that scans every few minutes the executing processes and kill the
  game process if it finds it.

Many other possibilities are possible for rending impossible the playing of the game.

You may also set up the protection yourself using the additional account,
then ask someone to change the account login password and keep it a secret.
The friend in this case does not need to have a good knowledge of Windows
and EFS will be an effective and simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a firewall exception that can allow you to block the website of the game or the game itself.

Although, a little bit off-topic, if you are having problems with playing games then why don't you make a schedule and see if you can follow it for the day. For example, going to the gym.